# Building ffmpeg libraries for third party usage

Tags: c, ffmpeg, dynamic-linking

I am trying to create bindings for FFmpeg in Elixir programming language and would love to handle FFmpeg binaries for users of my library.

The whole flow is as follows:

1. Write some function definition in Elixir
2. Implement it in in C using ffmpeg libs
3. Compile C code as shared library
4. When running application, Erlang Virtual Machine will load my dynamic library

The question is how to compile and include ffmpeg libs in my shared lib so that users of my Elixir lib don't have to install any native dependencies.

Here is what I was trying:

1. Compile ffmpeg libs as shared ones. When my Elixir lib is compiling, it downloads precompiled ffmpeg archive, extracts its content and links to it when compiling native functions. I realized that this still won't work as ffmpeg shared libs depend on other shared libs that user has to install on their own.
2. Compile ffmpeg libs as static ones and include them in my native shared library using --whole-archive linker option. Here I am getting

/usr/bin/ld: ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(vp9lpf_16bpp.o): warning: relocation against `ff_pw_1' in read-only section` .text'
/usr/bin/ld: ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(cavsdsp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The command I am using

```
cc -fPIC -I/home/michal/.asdf/installs/erlang/25.1/erts-13.1/include -Iffmpeg_build/include -Ic_src/xav -shared -DXAV_DEBUG=1 c_src/xav/xav_nif.c c_src/xav/reader.c c_src/xav/utils.c -o /home/michal/Repos/xav/_build/test/lib/xav/priv/libxav.so -Lffmpeg_build/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavformat -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

FFmpeg configuration

```
./configure \
--prefix="$PWD/ffmpeg_build" \
--extra-cflags="-fPIC -I$PWD/ffmpeg_build/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$PWD/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--enable-pic
--disable-programs
```

Does anything that I am trying to do make sense to you?

When I am installing ffmpeg-libs package on Fedora, it depends on other shared libs that are automatically downlaoded but what I would love to achieve is to provide self-contained ffmpeg build that can be used in other shared libraries.

Comment: _Why?_ You're already doing the _simple_ (i.e. "best") way: have the distro (e.g. `dnf` for fedora or `apt-get` for ubuntu) install the `ffmpeg` libraries. Just have the install script for your stuff, do (e.g.) `sudo dnf install ffmpeg-libs` if they're not already installed. For your sanity, and reducing multiple copies of libraries, don't embed standard libs in _your_ install. If you do so, you "own" the ffmpeg libs and their _maintenance/bug fixing_, for _all_ the dependent libs also. If the distro installs them, _they_ "own" the support/maintenance.

Comment: On the one hand you are correct but on the other hand what I wanted to achieve is that user doesn't have to install native libraries on its own and doesn't have to handle compiler flags like C_INCLUDE_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I could also provide one, very specific version of ffmpeg. The problem is when my library  requires e.g. ffmpeg 6.0 while user needs ffmpeg 5.0 on its system for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches:

1. Have the user download/install `ffmpeg` from their distro. As I mentioned, you could have *your* install script detect and do this, possibly prompting the user to allow this. Just live with the results. If `ffmpeg` libs are downrev, just report that and terminate.
2. Use a container (e.g.) https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/
3. Add a copy of `ffmpeg` to *your* package (container or not).

---

But, decide on your target audience. Since [AFAICT] you're creating an `elixir` plugin for `ffmpeg`, I'm assuming your target audience is `elixir` *programmers* [and, *not* non-programmer end users].

So, you should, possibly, assume more skill. Thus, a few commands might be okay instead of a one stop "do it all" approach.

You could distribute your stuff (e.g.) as a `github` repo. The `README.md` could give the instructions (even if it's just to execute an install script).

---

You should look at how some other software handles these issues. For example, https://transmissionbt.com/

At a minimum, I'd have a "top level" directory that contains *everything* (e.g.) `/usr/local/myproject` or `/opt/myproject` or `/home/user/myproject`

Under that directory, have whatever subdirectories you need (e.g.):

```
/opt/myproject
    bin
        start.sh
        real_program
    lib
    ffmpeg
    elixir
    erlang
    plugins
```

Look at `/usr/bin/firefox`. It is a script. It finds the necessary directories and sets environment variables (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH`, etc.) and then does an `exec` of its real binary.

---

In your `git` source repo, you could have a subdirectory (e.g. `ffmpeg`) that is a remote to the *real* `git` repo for `ffmpeg`. That is, either `git remote` or `git submodule`. Then, you can choose when to update your local copy and to which branch/tag of the remote repo (e.g. `git rebase`)